# documentation of the swagger this returning this error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui

InvalidOperationException: Conflicting schemaIds: Identical schemaIds detected for types BTBTems.DataModel.Ticket.ChamadoDM and BTBTems.DataModel.Chamado.ChamadoDM. See config settings - "UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds" or "CustomSchemaIds" for a workaround

Comment: Startup
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
         services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
               c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Core Api", Description = "Swagger Core Api" })
            );
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        { app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Core Api");
            });
}

Answer (score 2):

Update your swagger config file (*..\AppStart\SwaggerConfig.cs*) to call `c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds()`:

```
         GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    //....
                    c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();  // <-- add this
                    //....
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {

                });
```